# Firestore document not deleted

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to delete a doc from Firestore, I don't get an error but the document is still in the database: simply as that, it keeps on being in the collection it belongs to.

The cloud function is:

```
exports.countdowns_crud = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    var req = request;
    var res = response;

    if (request.method === 'DELETE') {
        const countdownId = request.path.split('/')[1];

        const deleteOperation = db.DeleteCountdown(countdownId);

        if (!deleteOperation) {
            console.log('Delete operation result: ', deleteOperation);

            cors(req, res, () => {
                res.status(204).send("DELETED");
            });
        }
        else {
            console.error(addOperation);
            cors(req, res, () => {
                res.status(500).send("INTERNAL SERVER ERROR");
            });
        };

        return;
    }

    cors(req, res, () => {
        res.status(405).send("NOT ALLOWED");
        return;
    });

})
```

The DeleteCountdown function is in another module:

```
module.exports = {

  DeleteCountdown: (countdownId) => {
    const countdownsCollection = app.firestore.collection('countdowns');

    countdownsCollection.doc(countdownId).delete()
      .then((res) => {
        console.log('Result: ', res);
        return null;
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.error(`unable to delete the countdown ${countdowmnId}: ${e}`);
        return e;
      });
  }

}
```

This is the logic in a google cloud function, which it's correctly invoked by my react app upon deletion. The passed id is correct, no error is returned, but the doc keeps on living in the collection.

Comment: Are your rules set up to allow for deletes?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started?authuser=0

Comment: Ok, i did not. But still, with the following permissions:

service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /{document=**} {
        allow read, write, update, delete;
        }
    }
}

it's neither giving me errors nor deleting the documents.

Comment: If you are running this in Cloud Functions, please edit the question to show the entire, minimal function that doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: Sorry, i made a better debug and i fixed it. The id was wrong after a given change. The split function is not ideal, this is just a prototype, i would add express.js very soon so i will basically be using the helpers tools for url manipulation.

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't need this question any more, please delete it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, no error and `null` returned (exactly the same when it works) because I forgot to set the rules to allow writes (or specifically deletions) directly in the Firebase console or by the firestore.rules files